# How to properly mock a node module for jest unit testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm new to jest and just want to implement a unit test for a simple function that uses a third party node module.

function to test (say it lives in utilFolder.js):

```
import moduleName from 'third_party_module'
const util = {
   simple_function() {
      const name = moduleName.func1();
   }
}

export default util;
```

test file:

```
import util from "utilFolder";
import moduleName  from 'third_party_module';
jest.mock("third_party_module", () => ({
   func1: jest.fn()
}));

describe("was mocked functions called", () {
  test("was mocked functions called??", () => {
      util.simple_function();
      expect(moduleName.func1).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Error:

> Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.

Any help please?

Comment: Works for me (after fixing the typos).  Did you bootstrap with `create-react-app`?  Are you doing anything special with `babel` or `webpack`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `jest.mock` mock the module. Here is the working example:

`util.js`:

```js
import moduleName from './third_party_module';

const util = {
  simple_function() {
    const name = moduleName.func1();
  }
};

export default util;
```

`third_party_module.js`:

```js
export default {
  func1() {}
};
```

`util.spec.js`:

```js
import util from './util';
import moduleName from './third_party_module';

jest.mock('./third_party_module', () => ({
  func1: jest.fn()
}));

describe('was mocked functions called', () => {
  test('was mocked functions called??', () => {
    util.simple_function();
    expect(moduleName.func1).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/54729837/util.spec.js (8.414s)
  was mocked functions called
    ✓ was mocked functions called?? (4ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.742s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/54729837